# find ordered list in hql by max different between values with max dates

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql

I have a table in postgres

```
CREATE TABLE employer_visit(
  employer_id                     INTEGER REFERENCES employer,
  visit_counter                   INTEGER NOT NULL, -- counter on current date
  visit_before_date_total_counter INTEGER NOT NULL, -- total, since service has started
  date                            DATE,
  PRIMARY KEY(employer_id, date)
);
```

I need to find top employers by visits from last 30 days - (ordered list of `employer_visit` by diff between visit_before_date_total_counter in last record and last record 30 days ago)

I have tried this hql query

```
Query<EmployerVisit> query = getSession().createQuery(
    "SELECT ev FROM EmployerVisit ev " +
        "WHERE ev.employerVisitId.date = (SELECT MAX (groupedEv.employerVisitId.date) FROM EmployerVisit groupedEv " +
        "WHERE groupedEv.employerVisitId.employerId = ev.employerVisitId.employerId) " +
        "AND " +
        "ev.employerVisitId.date = (SELECT MAX (groupedEv2.employerVisitId.date) < :date FROM EmployerVisit groupedEv2 " +
        "WHERE groupedEv2.employerVisitId.employerId = ev.employerVisitId.employerId) " +
        "ORDER BY (groupedEv.visitCounter + groupedEv.visitBeforeDateTotalCounter) - (groupedEv2.visitCounter + groupedEv2.visitBeforeDateTotalCounter) DESC"
).setMaxResults(size).setParameter("date", calendar.getTime());
```

But it falls with

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Invalid path: 'groupedEv.visitCounter'
```

Becouse the table `groupedEv` doesn't exist after `ORDER BY`

It is possible to use depricated SqlQuery for this case in hibernate but I prefere hql, please help, thanks.

UPDATE! - Entity and EmbeddedId Class without setters and getters

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employer_visit")
public class EmployerVisit {

  @EmbeddedId
  private EmployerVisitId employerVisitId;

  @Column(name = "visit_counter")
  private Integer visitCounter;

  @Column(name = "visit_before_date_total_counter")
  private Integer visitBeforeDateTotalCounter;

  public EmployerVisit() {
    employerVisitId = new EmployerVisitId();
    visitCounter = 0;
    visitBeforeDateTotalCounter = 0;
  }
}

@Embeddable
public class EmployerVisitId implements Serializable {

  @Column(name = "employer_id")
  private Integer employerId;

  @Column(name = "date")
  private Date date;

  public EmployerVisitId() {
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post `EmployerVisit` entity class?

Answer (score 0):

This is the Answer

```
Query<Object> query = getSession().createQuery(
            "SELECT ev, SUM(ev.visitCounter) AS counter FROM EmployerVisit AS ev " +
            "WHERE ev.employerVisitId.date > :date "         +
            "GROUP BY ev.employerVisitId.employerId, ev.employerVisitId.date " +
            "ORDER BY counter DESC").setMaxResults(size).setParameter("date", calendar.getTime());

List<EmployerVisitDto> top = new ArrayList<>();
for (Object result : query.list()) {
      Object[] dividedResult = (Object[]) result;
      EmployerVisit employerVisit = (EmployerVisit) dividedResult[0];

      EmployerVisitDto employerVisitDto = getEmployer(employerVisit.getEmployerId()).toEmployerVisitDto();
      employerVisitDto.setPeopleVisited(((Long) dividedResult[1]).intValue());
      top.add(employerVisitDto);
}
return top;
```